# instantiate a subclassed uitableviewcell programatically initwithstyle does not show separator

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

in iOS5.0 I'm trying to instantiate a subclassed uitableviewcell programatically with initwithstyle. the code I'm using is below. When I instantiate using UITableViewCell alloc... i get the table separators, but when I do so using thumbCell alloc, the table row separator lines do not appear, the text that I setup in the thumbCell does not appear.. and the screen appears all white.. Pls help me understand what am I doing wrong..

In my ViewController

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"GroupCell";
    thumbCell *cell = [self.testTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [self.testTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier]; (this works)

    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[thumbCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
       //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];(this works)
    }
    [cell.textLabel setText:@"test"];
    return cell;
}
```

and in thumbCell subclass

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self.textLabel setText:@"thumbCell"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
 static NSString *identifier = @"GroupCell";
thumbCell *cell = [self.testTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
//UITableViewCell *cell = [self.testTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier]; (this works)

if(!cell) {
    cell = [[thumbCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
   //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];(this works)
}
NSInteger sectionRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
[cell setCellBackground:sectionRows:row];
[cell.textLabel setText:@"test"];

return cell;
}
```

In thumbCell class (custom cell class)

```
-(void)setCellBackground:(NSInteger)sectionRows:(NSInteger)row
{
UIImage *rowBackground;
UIImage *selectionBackground;

if (row == 0 && row == sectionRows - 1)
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRow.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRowSelected.png"];
}
else if (row == 0)
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topRow.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topRowSelected.png"];
}
else if (row == sectionRows - 1)
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRow.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRowSelected.png"];
}
else
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRow.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRowSelected.png"];
}
((UIImageView *)self.backgroundView).image = rowBackground;
((UIImageView *)self.selectedBackgroundView).image = selectionBackground;
}
```

Comment: I am planning to have some more UiControls in the custom subclassed UItableviewCell, so I have to go with subclassing..

Comment: Answer Edited. In **thumbCell** class you can use **self addsubview** as many controls as you like. Making another function in **thumbCell** and calling it from **cellForRowAtIndexPath**